# JFace / SWT TextArea

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have come across a stickler of a problem.

In the swing environment there is a function that is available TextArea in the AWT Components. However this is not present in either the JFace or the Swing environment.

has anybody come across a solution? Would I have to make my own Interface as a work around?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what function might that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SWT `Text` control for simple single or multi-line text, or you can use `StyledText` if you want text with fonts and colors.